# Outlook.live.com - does opening a junk email trigger Open message tracking?

Tags: email, spam-prevention, outlook.com

Generally, when mail providers place a suspected spam email in the Junk folder, and then a user opens that email, the content is blocked from loading so as to avoid triggering an `Open` email event in the sender's email delivery tracking software. This means no images are loaded.

However, I've noticed that on outlook.live.com certain emails placed in the Junk folder still load image content when opened, despite the web client in many cases displays a warning message saying content has been blocked from loading for this exact purpose.

Why are images loading for junk emails? And will this allow email-opening event tracking?

Comment: At a guess, the email probably has the image encoded within the body of the text. Therefore it’s safe to display it on the basis that there are no requests going to a third party server to get an image.

Comment: Wouldn't they show up as an attachment in the email?

Comment: Not if the image is base64 encoded and embedded directly into the HTML of the email. This answer shows code to embed an encoded image of a red dot into HTML https://stackoverflow.com/a/8499716

Comment: Incidentally, checking one email, Outlook.live.com seems to be pulling an imgur.com link. Quite interesting.